# When two div's overlapped - the color of the first one should be changed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the div's background color on "white" whenever it's overlapping with a blue div. I'm trying my best, but obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Please, if it's don't bother you, help me understand why my code is not working.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/RaizRus/pen/zYrNGEK

```js
let elOne = document.querySelector('.elementOne').getBoundingClientRect();
let elTwo = document.querySelector('.elementTwo').getBoundingClientRect();
let topOverlap = elOne.top + elOne.height;
let bottomOverlap = elOne.bottom + elOne.height;


if(elTwo.top <= topOverlap || elTwo.bottom <= bottomOverlap) {
  document.querySelector('.elementOne').classList.add('white');
} else {
  if(document.querySelector('.elementOne').classList.contains('white'))   {
    document.querySelector('.elementOne').classList.remove('white');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
  background: grey;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.elementOne {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:9;
}
.elementTwo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1040px;
}
.white {
  background-color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="elementOne"></div>
  <div class="elementTwo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: When you scroll down the page, the `blue` div moves. So when it moves to the point that it overlaps the pink one, do you want to change the background? Is that?

Comment: I think your code is only running once on page load. You need to put your javascript in a function, and then call that function in response to the container scrolling.

Comment: this will give you the values === window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
        console.log(window.scrollY);
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun one, feel free to have a look!

The key pieces you were missing are:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {});
```

and

```
window.pageYOffset
```

```js
let elOne = document.querySelector('.elementOne').getBoundingClientRect();
let elTwo = document.querySelector('.elementTwo').getBoundingClientRect();


window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let topOverlap = elTwo.top - elOne.bottom;
  let bottomOverlap = elTwo.bottom - elOne.top;
  let classList = document.querySelector('.elementOne').classList;
  if (window.pageYOffset >= topOverlap && window.pageYOffset <= bottomOverlap) {
    if (!classList.contains('white')) {
      classList.add('white');
    }
  } else {
    if (classList.contains('white')) {
      classList.remove('white');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.elementOne {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
}

.elementTwo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1040px;
}

.white {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="elementOne"></div>
  <div class="elementTwo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question: Is there a way to do it without window.pageYOffset? (for example, if using the virtual scroll library without native scroll behavior)